# Pascal/Python Factorization Program

Tags: python, pascal, factorization

I have made two programs to find the prime factors of a number, one in python and one in pascal. I would like to factorize 600851475143; the python program factorizes it instantly. However, the pascal one does't finish in a reasonable amount of time. Is it to do with the different programming language or how I coded the one in Pascal? I used recursion in the python one but not in the pascal one. Why does the pascal program not also complete instantly?

python:

```
def findLowestFactor(num, factors=None):
    if factors:
        start = factors[-1]
    else:
        start = 2
    for i in range(start, int(num)):
        if num%i == 0:
            return i
    else:
        return False


def findPrimeFactors(num, factors=None):
    if factors is None:
        factors = []
    factor = findLowestFactor(num, factors)
    if factor:
        factors.append(factor)
        findPrimeFactors(num/factor, factors)
        return factors
    else: 
        factors.append(int(num))
        return factors


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        factors = findPrimeFactors(num)
        print(*factors)
```

Pascal:

```
program Primes;

var
  input:string;
  num:integer;
  error:integer;
  factor:integer;
  factors:array of integer;
  found: boolean;
  start:integer;
  x:integer;


begin
  writeln(600851475143);
  (*Repeat untill exit*)
  while true do
  begin
    (*Repeat untill valid input*)
    repeat
    write('Enter a number: ');
    readln(input);
    val(input, num, error);
    if error = 1 then
      writeln('Not an integer');
    until error = 0;

    writeln;

    (*set up list*)
    SetLength(factors, 0);
    factor := 0;
    found := false;
    (*while num is not prime*)
    while found = false do
    begin
      (*start from largest factor found for efficiency*)
      if length(factors) > 0 then
        start := factors[length(factors)-1]
      else
        start := 2;
      (*loop through numbers from number in start var to current num*)
      for factor := start to num do
      begin
        (*if there are no more factors*)
        if num / factor = 1 then
          begin;
            (*add final factor to list*)
            SetLength(factors, length(factors)+1);
            factors[length(factors)-1] := factor;
            (*break out of the loop*)
            found := True;
          end
        (*if factor is found*)
        else if num mod factor = 0 then
          begin
            (*divide num by found factor*)
            num := num div factor;
            (*add the factor*)
            SetLength(factors, length(factors)+1);
            factors[length(factors)-1] := factor;
            (*break for efficiency*)
            Break;
          end;


      end;
    end;

    write('Prime Factors: ');
    for x:= 0 to length(factors)-1 do
      write(factors[x], ' ');
    writeln;
    writeln;

  end;

end.
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Which Pascal did you use? Also, the Python code is nicely structured, while the Pascal code is almost one single block. The approach seems to be different too, so it could well be explained by that difference. Also note that  600851475143 is larger than 32 bits, so if an integer is 32 bits in Pascal, it might not work as expected. Python probably uses the right data type depending on the number you give it. So there can be several factors.

Comment: FWIW, instead of Integer, try to use Int64 for the relevant variables in Pascal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I translated your Python code to Pascal. I used Delphi, but it should compile in FreePascal too. It returns instantaneously:

```
type
  TIntArray = array of Integer; // Delphi: TArray<Integer>;

function findLowestFactor(num: Int64; factors: TIntArray): Integer;
var
  start: Integer;
  i: Int64;
begin
  if Length(factors) > 0 then
    start := factors[High(factors)]  // factors[-1] in Python, i.e. last entry.
  else
    start := 2;
  i := start;
  while i < num do        // Int64 can not be used as index in for-loop... 
  begin                   // ... so I use while loop.
    if num mod i = 0 then // Python: if num % i == 0:
      Exit(i);            // return i
    Inc(i);
  end;
  Exit(0);
end;

procedure findPrimeFactors(num: Int64; var factors: TIntArray);
var
  factor: Integer;
begin
  factor := findLowestFactor(num, factors);
  if factor > 0 then
  begin 
    // Delphi: factors := factors + [factor];
    SetLength(factors, Length(factors) + 1);
    factors[High(factors)] := factor;

    findPrimeFactors(num div factor, factors);
  end
  else
  begin
    // Delphi: factors := factors + [Integer(num)];
    SetLength(factors, Length(factors) + 1);
    factors[High(factors)] := Integer(num);
  end;
end;

const
  testValue: Int64 = 600851475143;

var
  factors: TIntArray;
  i: Integer;
  result: Int64;

begin
  // Instead of user input, I use the testValue above.
  Writeln('test value: ', testValue);
  findPrimeFactors(testValue, factors);
  result := 1;
  for i in factors do
  begin
    Write(i:8);
    result := result * i;
  end;
  Writeln;
  Writeln('multiplied: ', result);
  Readln;
end.
```

**Note that I had to use Int64 in some places**. I assume Python does this automatically, but not Pascal. Perhaps the use of Integers in some places made your code so slow.

I omitted the user input parts of the code (Readln etc.), just used the constant value you gave. But, as I said, it returns instantaneously, with the right values (see variable result).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yea, the problem was that I wasn't using Int64 as I am new to Pascal. I'll read through and try to understand your Pascal version using recursion. I tried to translate it myself before but wasn't good enough at Pascal yet. :)

Comment: Note that I wrote this in Delphi. There, instead of the SetLength() line and the line after that, you can simply do: `factors := factors + [factor];`. But I don't think this is possible in the other implementations of Pascal.